# Graphics primitives - graphic design in _Mathematica_

Tags: graphics

I noticed [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53266/illustrator-depth-illusion-effect#53266) in Graphic Design SE. I wondered whether it was possible / any easier in *Mathematica*? Image reporoduced below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Moving the comment to an answer:

```
ListPlot3D[RandomReal[1, {10, 3}], BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Texture[ColorNegate@
    Rasterize@
     Grid@Table[Graphics[Disk[], ImageSize -> 7], {25}, {15}]], 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &), 
 Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, Mesh -> None, ViewPoint -> Top, 
 Background -> Black, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]